# Valac missing generated header

Tags: header-files, vala, vapi

I have two files, `client.vala` and `lib.vapi`.
The VAPI defines a class (that would usually talk to C code):

```
class Toplevel.Sub.CClass
{
    public uint i;
}
```

And `client.vala` uses the class:

```
class Toplevel.Sub.UserClass
{
    public Toplevel.Sub.CClass c_class;
}

int main()
{
    var cls = new Toplevel.Sub.UserClass();
    cls.c_class.i = 0;
    return 0;
}
```

When I attempt to compile the program, I get an error:

```
$ valac client.vala lib.vapi
/tmp/bug/client.vala.c:7:20: fatal error: client.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
error: cc exited with status 256
Compilation failed: 1 error(s), 0 warning(s)
```

The compiler seems to want a header generated for the functions in `client.vala`.

Is this a bug or am I missing something?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with that vapi file? Is there an additional C library that you would like to access from Vala code? A Vapi file only serves as a placeholder for `valac` to read and is not useful to the C compiler as it is not translated to C code. Thus, the C compiler does not know about `class Toplevel.Sub.CClass`. So you should also supply the C header that comes with that library to the compiler by, for example, putting it into your build directory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've discovered something I didn't know about the Vala compiler. `client.h` is the default C header name generated by the compiler when no alternative is provided. It has used the basename of the source Vala file. You can change this using the `cheader_filename` CCode detail. Change what you have in your VAPI to:

```
[CCode (cheader_filename = "my_real_c_header.h")]
class Toplevel.Sub.CClass
{
    public uint i;
}
```

and you will see the include is now `#include "my_real_c_header.h"`

By the way if you compile with `valac client.vala --vapididr . --pkg lib` you will see the header is included as `#include <my_real_c_header.h>`. Personally I think VAPIs should be used with the `--pkg` option.

If you are literally using `Toplevel.Sub.CClass` to 'usually talk to C code' then you have misunderstood the purpose of a VAPI. I take 'talk to' to mean calling various C functions and collecting the results so they can be presented in a more Vala friendly way to the rest of your program. So it is a wrapper interface.

A VAPI contains instructions to the Vala compiler to translate names into the right names for the C interface. For example you might have a very simple C function, `void top_level_do_something ()`, that you want to use in Vala. In Vala it helps to use a namespace so the VAPI could be:

```
[CCode (cheader_filename = "my_real_c_header.h")]
namespace TopLevel {
    [CCode (cname = "top_level_do_something")]
    public void do_something ();
}
```

You can then call this in Vala with `TopLevel.do_something ()` and the compiler would write this out as `top_level_do_something ()` in C.

Take a look at [Writing a VAPI Manually](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/Vala/LegacyBindings) for more details.

Comment: Thank you @AIThomas -- I modified my code to _actually call_ a C function, and after getting the same error, specifying the `cheader_filename` did the trick.
For anyone else facing the same problem, the now working code is [here](http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=50505437598368551388).